# OpenEdge Progress 10.1B export

Tags: openedge, progress-db

I have look at other that have been trying to get data from an OpenEdge Progress database.
I have the same problem, but there is a backup routine on the windows file server that dump the data every night. I have the *.pbk and a 1K *.st file. How can I get the data out of the dump file in a form I can use?

Or is't not possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *.pbk file is probably a backup (ProBacKup).  You can restore it on another system with compatible characteristics (same byte order, same release of Progress OpenEdge).  Sometimes that is helpful if the other system has better connectivity or licensing.

To extract the data from a database, either the original or a restored backup, you have some possibilities:

1) A pre-written extract program.  Possibly provided by whoever created the application.  Such a program might create simple text files.

2) A development license that permits you to write your own extract program.  The output of the "showcfg" command will reveal whether or not you have a development license.

3) Regardless of license type you can use "proutil dbName -C dump tableName" to export the data but this will result in binary output that you probably will not be able to read or convert.  (It is usually used in conjunction with "proutil load").

4) Depending again on the license that you have you might be able to dump data with the data administration tool.  If you have a runtime only license you may need to specify the -rx startup parameter.

5) If your database has been configured to allow SQL access via ODBC or JDBC you could connect with a SQL tool and extract data that way.

Comment: The Company that created the program is no longer in business. When I run Showcfg I get, Product name=Client networking, user limit, Expiration Date=None, serial #, control #, version 10.2B, port number. I can do everything in DA, but export and import, is that because I don't provide username and password when selecting
Database Connect?

Comment: Your license type is client networking. This means you will only be able to execute compiled code. You will not be able to create or serve databases, you will not be able to execute code that has not been compiled with a compiler license. So unless you have another install of Progress with a database license attached you will not be able to do anything.

Comment: Thanks for the information, looks like I have to find someone that can create the code, do you know of a website for Progress developer where I could find someone or do you do it for a fee?